# Vehicle reloading at depot and continuing

Tags: python, or-tools

I try to generate a delivery plan using ORTOOL and Python.
My constraints are the following:

1. Each vehicle has a start time and an end time
2. Each vehicle has its own capacity of stored items, taken at the depot
3. Each vehicle has its own speed.

For 1 and 3, it works fine using AddDimensionWithVehicleTransits.
For the second constraint, if the vehicle is empty, it has to return to the depot to retrieve items and start again.

I've seen the refuel example, so setting a node with a capacity < 0 works fine. But in my case, the depot is the refuel point and the solver doesn't make the vehicle return to it.

My dimension is set like that:

```
routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleCapacity(
    capacity_evaluator,
    0,
    [capacity[vehicle].get('capacity', dataconfig.default_capacity) for vehicle in data.vehicles], 
    True, 
    'Capacity'
)
```

Basically, with a max capacity of 4:

```
Route for Vehicle1
[LOCATION, START, CAPACITY]
['Depot', '4:0', 0]
[u'7', '9:0', 1]
[u'6', '10:0', 4]
['Depot', '11:00', 4]
```

What I need:

```
Route for Vehicle1
[LOCATION, START, CAPACITY]
['Depot', '4:0', 0]
[u'Location1', '9:0', 1]
[u'Location2', '10:0', 4]
['Depot', '11:00', 0]
[u'Location3', '12:0', 1]
[u'Location4', '13:0', 2]
[u'Location5', '14:0', 4]
['Depot', '15:00', 0]
```

Any idea about how to put the refuel point to the depot ?

Regards

Comment: the solver is a tsp internally so you can't visit two time the same node.
You must create a "duplicate" of the depot with a slack var (like in refuel) to empty/refill your vehicle.....

Comment: If I do that, only one vehicle will visit it. So I imagine that I have to create one for each vehicle with no cost / no penalty so it is visited only when required ? If many refuel are required, then the number of required refuel is not predictable but bound. I'll try that, thank you !

Comment: It succeeded. I have to take care about the amount of "optional depot" that I create otherwise the solver hangs. One for each vehicle is ok, two for each vehicle makes the time to solve the problem from 5s to more than 5min (I don't know if it succeeds at some point). I didn't use a slackvar, but AddDimensionWithVehicleTransitAndCapacity with an evaluator per vehicle to generate the right negative capacity returned by the optional depot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It succeeded with the comment of Mizux Dev, either with the slackvar or AddDimensionWithVehicleTransitAndCapacity using optional depot with refill capacity.

Comment: It would be great if you could provide some more details. Code would also be helpful.